# How to pop item from list and push it back to list based on condition using python

Tags: python, python-2.7, list, web-crawler

I have list with urls for crawling.['http://domain1.com','http://domain1.com/page1','http://domain2.com']

Code:

```
prev_domain = ''
while urls:
    url = urls.pop()
    if base_url(url) == prev_domain: # base_url is custom function return domain of an url
        urls.append(url) # is this is possible?
        continue 
    else:
        crawl(url)
```

Basically I dont want to crawl webpages of same domain continuously. Continuosly crawling a domain url, return http response status code with **429: Too Many Requests. The user has sent too many requests in a given amount of time ("rate limiting")**. To by-pass this issue, I'm planning to go with below logic.

Loop through all items in the list and compare current element base url with previously processed element base url.

If base urls are different then process for next step, otherwise do not process current element, just append this element to the same list.

Note : If urls in list are of same domain, make delay in processing each element and then execute.

Please provide your thoughts.

Comment: Problem description is bit confusing, can you provide the sample output which you are expecting ?

Comment: @BharatJogdand i have edited my question for better understanding.

Answer (score 1):

Your algorithm is almost correct, but not the implementation:

```
>>> L = [1,2,3]
>>> L.pop()
3
>>> L.append(3)
>>> L
[1, 2, 3]
```

That's why your program loops forever: if the domain is the same as the previous domain, you just append then pop then append, then.... What you need is not a stack, it's a round robin:

```
>>> L.pop()
3
>>> L.insert(0, 3)
>>> L
[3, 1, 2]
```

Let's take a shuffled list of permutations of "abcd":

```
>>> L = [('b', 'c', 'd', 'a'), ('d', 'c', 'b', 'a'), ('a', 'c', 'd', 'b'), ('c', 'd', 'a', 'b'), ('b', 'd', 'a', 'c'), ('b', 'a', 'd', 'c'), ('b', 'c', 'a', 'd'), ('a', 'b', 'd', 'c'), ('d', 'a', 'b', 'c'), ('a', 'b', 'c', 'd'), ('d', 'c', 'a', 'b'), ('a', 'd', 'c', 'b'), ('d', 'a', 'c', 'b'), ('c', 'd', 'b', 'a'), ('d', 'b', 'c', 'a'), ('d', 'b', 'a', 'c'), ('a', 'd', 'b', 'c'), ('b', 'd', 'c', 'a'), ('c', 'b', 'd', 'a'), ('c', 'a', 'b', 'd'), ('b', 'a', 'c', 'd')]
```

The first letter is the `domain`. Here's a slightly modified version of your code:

```
>>> prev = None
>>> while L:
...     e = L.pop()
...     if L and e[0] == prev:
...         L.insert(0, e)
...     else:
...         print(e)
...         prev = e[0]
('b', 'a', 'c', 'd')
('c', 'a', 'b', 'd')
('b', 'd', 'c', 'a')
('a', 'd', 'b', 'c')
('d', 'b', 'a', 'c')
('c', 'd', 'b', 'a')
('d', 'a', 'c', 'b')
('a', 'd', 'c', 'b')
('d', 'c', 'a', 'b')
('a', 'b', 'c', 'd')
('d', 'a', 'b', 'c')
('a', 'b', 'd', 'c')
('b', 'c', 'a', 'd')
('c', 'd', 'a', 'b')
('a', 'c', 'd', 'b')
('d', 'c', 'b', 'a')
('b', 'c', 'd', 'a')
('c', 'b', 'd', 'a')
('d', 'b', 'c', 'a')
('b', 'a', 'd', 'c')
('b', 'd', 'a', 'c')
```

The modification is: `if L and`, because if the last element of the list domain is `prev`, then you'll loop forever with your one element list: pop, same as prev, insert, pop, ...(as with pop/append)

Here's another option: create a dict `domain -> list of urls`:

```
>>> d = {}
>>> for e in L:
...     d.setdefault(e[0], []).append(e)
>>> d
{'b': [('b', 'c', 'd', 'a'), ('b', 'd', 'a', 'c'), ('b', 'a', 'd', 'c'), ('b', 'c', 'a', 'd'), ('b', 'd', 'c', 'a'), ('b', 'a', 'c', 'd')], 'd': [('d', 'c', 'b', 'a'), ('d', 'a', 'b', 'c'), ('d', 'c', 'a', 'b'), ('d', 'a', 'c', 'b'), ('d', 'b', 'c', 'a'), ('d', 'b', 'a', 'c')], 'a': [('a', 'c', 'd', 'b'), ('a', 'b', 'd', 'c'), ('a', 'b', 'c', 'd'), ('a', 'd', 'c', 'b'), ('a', 'd', 'b', 'c')], 'c': [('c', 'd', 'a', 'b'), ('c', 'd', 'b', 'a'), ('c', 'b', 'd', 'a'), ('c', 'a', 'b', 'd')]}
```

Now, take an element of every `domain` and clear the dict, then loop until the dict is empty:

```
>>> while d:
...     for k, vs in d.items():
...          e = vs.pop()
...          print (e)
...     d = {k: vs for k, vs in d.items() if vs} # clear the dict
...
('b', 'a', 'c', 'd')
('d', 'b', 'a', 'c')
('a', 'd', 'b', 'c')
('c', 'a', 'b', 'd')
('b', 'd', 'c', 'a')
('d', 'b', 'c', 'a')
('a', 'd', 'c', 'b')
('c', 'b', 'd', 'a')
('b', 'c', 'a', 'd')
('d', 'a', 'c', 'b')
('a', 'b', 'c', 'd')
('c', 'd', 'b', 'a')
('b', 'a', 'd', 'c')
('d', 'c', 'a', 'b')
('a', 'b', 'd', 'c')
('c', 'd', 'a', 'b')
('b', 'd', 'a', 'c')
('d', 'a', 'b', 'c')
('a', 'c', 'd', 'b')
('b', 'c', 'd', 'a')
('d', 'c', 'b', 'a')
```

The output is more uniform.

Answer (score 0):

Check the following code snippet,

```
urls = ['http://domain1.com','http://domain1.com/page1','http://domain2.com']

crawl_for_urls = {}
for url in urls:
    domain = base_url(url)
    if domain not in crowl_for_urls:
        crawl_for_urls.update({domain:url})
        crawl(url)
```

`crawl()` will be called only for unique domain.

Or you can use:

```
urls = ['http://domain1.com','http://domain1.com/page1','http://domain2.com']

crawl_for_urls = {}
for url in urls:
    domain = base_url(url)
    if domain not in crowl_for_urls:
        crawl_for_urls.update({domain:[url]})
        crawl(url)
    else:
        crawl_for_urls.get(domain, []).append(url)
```

This way you can categories the URL's based on domain and also can use `crawl()` for unique domain.